# Python - Pygame script will run in shell but not from script

Tags: python

This python script is part of a project but that doesn't have relevance. The script is attempting to use the pygame mixer module to load a wav file and play it; this works fine if I input the same code line-by-line in shell but not if I put it into a script and attempt to run it.

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('sound.wav')
mixer.music.play()
```

If I run the script line-by-line in shell, the sound plays through the speakers fine but if I put it into a script and do 'python3 playSound.py' then the audio file does not play.

Comment: Not working how?

Comment: If I run the script line-by-line in shell, the sound plays through the speakers fine but if I put it into a script and do 'python3 playSound.py' then the audio file does not play.

Comment: @JoshStafford please [edit] your question to provide additional information - comments can get lost.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the script was ending before the audio file had time to play so adding a sleep(*length of audio clip*) to the end of the file gave the script time to play the clip.